# Pandas Dataframe sum result is wrong

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, buffer-overflow

I make program using pandas and openpyxl to manipulate excel files,
series of data is:

```
l=[466629703, NA, 527821349, NA,734823364, NA,1667241489, NA,502673377, NA,491316417, NA,505520276, NA,2840580259, NA,1399526794, NA,468709318, NA,425220764, NA,409771252, NA,643692418, NA,1193809483, NA,353829950, NA,424820400, NA,406999623, NA,389293014, NA,1168972722, NA,420654309, NA,390431735, NA,356588382, NA]
```

[image: excel data]

```
deposit_sum = sep_df[sep_kward][deposit].dropna().astype(int).sum()
```

The result has to be 16188926398

But 11200862491 is the result of above code. Only one of file occurs that error. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Copy your dataframe as plain text code, please. Images are useless to help you.

Comment: kindly have a look on [how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard)

Comment: Thx for your reply. I'll edit it

Comment: maybe it has something to do with 32 vs 64 bit operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't typecast values to `int` after dropping `NaN's` convert the value to `int64` because this `2840580259.0` is out of range for integer value:

```
deposit_sum =df[0].dropna().astype('int64').sum()
#deposit_sum =sep_df[sep_kward][deposit].dropna().astype('int64').sum()
```

output of `deposit_sum`:

```
16188926398
```

Sample dataframe used:

```
NA=float('NaN')
l=[466629703, NA, 527821349, NA,734823364, NA,1667241489, NA,502673377, NA,491316417, NA,505520276, NA,2840580259, NA,1399526794, NA,468709318, NA,425220764, NA,409771252, NA,643692418, NA,1193809483, NA,353829950, NA,424820400, NA,406999623, NA,389293014, NA,1168972722, NA,420654309, NA,390431735, NA,356588382, NA]
df=pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Comment: Oh thx for your answer. I'll change code like that. Do you know why it happen?

Comment: @Sanghyeon.Jeon updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: @Sanghyeon.Jeon sir if your query is solved then try considering accepting the answer to indicate others that the issue is solved(click on the tick to make it green)...thanks **:)**

Comment: Sorry I'm late cause I'm on holiday. Thx for your detailed explanation